# Possible to accept GRE score and view it, but not report it to a university?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

From what I've read from the ETS and other sources, after finishing a GRE exam the system will give you the option to keep your scores, before you actually know the score.

If you decide to accept the score and then view it and realize it's bad, do you still have the option to not send it to any school, or is the step in which you select the schools to send it to before the step in which you view your score?

I'm wondering if I will be in either of the following situations:

1. I think I did well, but I have to select the universities before I actually see my score. I select the universities, and then see my actual score and see I didn't do so well.
2. I think I did poorly so I choose to not send my scores, but then I see my actual scores and find I did well, but now I have to pay extra to send my scores.

Ideally:

1. I accept my scores, then I'm able to view them. If I did well, I select my universities. If I did poorly, I don't select any university and just redo the GRE on a later date.

Thanks!

Comment: You always "keep" your scores - they're not deleted from the system. [This page](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/about/scoreselect/) goes over which scores, if any, are reported to schools you apply to.

Comment: Am I able to view the scores before selecting which universities to send them to? My question is, if I get a bad score can I NOT send them to the universities, but instead try to take the GRE again?

Comment: See the ETS FAQ.  In your additional score report, you can ask for "All" scores, "Most Recent" score, or "Any" specific date's scores to be sent.  https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/scores/send/asr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**.

You get to see your [unofficial test scores](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/faq/) on test day. Then you have the [option](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/about/scoreselect/) to send these scores or not.

Also, you can always change your mind by sending [additional score reports](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/scores/send/) after the test day for a fee. If you provide the schools the day of the test, they are free.

Comment: Hi Austin. I've updated my question with 2 scenarios to clear up what I mean. I'm already aware that I can order additional score reports after the test.

Comment: @sandy Updated. You really should read their FAQ. All of this information is there.